# Where do I ask a question regarding getting adb working properly for an android device?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am having trouble getting adb working properly for my Nook Color.  I am not sure whether I should be asking this question on Stack Overflow, even though it is not really specifically a programming question.  Where is the right place to ask this?

Comment: Is the Nook Color really an Android device?

Comment: yes. the nook color is an android based device.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) would fall under "software tools commonly used by programmers" so you should ask questions about it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Right, and [Apple Desktop Bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Desktop_Bus) would fall under really, really antique stuff that was good enough for a while but were happy not to have to deal with anymore.

Answer (score 5):

SO would probably accept such a question since it's a 'programming tool', but questions about setting up ADB for your device are also fine for [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) since it's a common requirement for many power-user functions.

If you want to ask over on AE I'd suggest taking a look through the [nook-color tag](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nook-color) first to see if it provides you with any solutions, and if not you can go ahead and ask your own question. Be sure to include what (if anything) you've tried, what OS your computer is running, and any information you have about the firmware version running on your Nook.